# ios 8 Background fetch is never called on device more than once time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background-fetch

I created a test app for background fetches on iOS. And it works fine on the simulator via Debug -> Simulate Background fetch. But on device with iOS 8 it called only once a day. How to force iOS to call it more often?

Here are my steps and code:

1) Project->Capabilities->Background modes->Background fetch

2) AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    localNotification.fireDate = now;
    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Background fetch!"];
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    NSInteger number = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
    number++;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = number;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Local notification should appear every time background fetch invoked.

Comment: Never called or called once a day, which is it? Your two statements are in total contradiction to each other. You can't force when it will occur, the OS decides when it will be, and if the OS is invoking it once a day then its working. When and how often it gets called depends on app device usage.

Comment: How often do you want it background fetch to be called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [performFetchWithCompletionHandler not getting called on fixed time interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161168/performfetchwithcompletionhandler-not-getting-called-on-fixed-time-interval)

Comment: @MartinH sorry for such contradiction, I mean that it calls only once and never calls more

Comment: @BlackFrog at least second time :)

Answer (score 0):

All you can do in this scenario is verify that your code works. The exact timing of when the background fetch happens is managed by iOS. This has been discussed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25529491/228981)

If you want to test your own code, you can do so with your app running in the Simulator by choosing `Xcode->Debug->Simulate Background Fetch`